# Issue with asp.net MVC partial view

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using knockout 2.3.0 in my MVC - 4 project. I have a partial view name UserInfo :

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && Model != null)
{
    <!-- ko with: UserInfo -->
    ....
    .......
    <! -- /ko -->

    //This is a custom html helper extension used to add script from partial... 
    //view to parent view. 

    @Html.Script(@<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {        
       viewModel.UserInfo(new UserInfo(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))); 
    })</script>)

}
else
{
     //show link to login
}
```

My problem is (actually i don't know whether it is a problem or not) that when user logged in and if they open inspect element window than the partial UserInfo view script section render something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(function () { 
  viewModel.UserInfo(new UserInfo({"UserId":2,"FirstName":"foo","LastName":"bar","Email":"xxx@gmail.com","Picture":"/path/to/profile/pic"})); 
 });
</script>
```

I don't know whether it is a good practice or not to show userinfo in such manner Or whats the security issues replated with this. Can anybody please explain me the issues related with this, if any and please suggest me the best way to handle this ?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd think it would be *not* secure?

Comment: I mentioned in my question that i don't know the security issue related with this but i want to know whether it is a good practice or not ??

Comment: `ViewModels` (as opposed to Entities) are meant to be sent over the wire (hence are Serializable). if there's something you don't want the client to see, don't put in in your ViewModel.

Comment: Anything that you send to the client side (unencrypted) has the potential to be read by someone poking around.  also, anything that can be posted can be made up (which is why you always do server side validation).  if your use case is to display the users information, then naturally you will need to have this data available, regardless of format.  internals like userid are perfectly fine if thats what you use to uniquely identify a user.